# variant change in lwc component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.itemList}" var="con" indexVar="index">    
    <div class="slds-p-top_small">        
        <aura:if isTrue="{!con.Contact.unformattedMobile}">
            <lightning:button variant="{!(and(v.phoneType == 'phone', v.indexVal == index)) ? 'brand' : 'neutral'}" onclick="{!c.SelectedNumber}" aura:id="phone" value= "{!index}" />
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!con.Contact.unformattedHome}">
            <lightning:button variant="{!(and(v.phoneType == 'fax', v.indexVal == index)) ? 'brand' : 'neutral'}" onclick="{!c.SelectedNumber}" aura:id="fax" value= "{!index}"/>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>


controller:

SelectedNumber : function(component, event, helper) {
        var btnClicked = event.getSource();
        var btnClickedId = btnClicked.getLocalId();
        component.set("v.phoneType",btnClickedId);
        var index = event.getSource().get("v.value");
        component.set("v.indexVal",index);
}
```

I have declared all the attributes and I am getting the values in the component.
I am trying to change the button variant on click of the button. Since it is in Iteration I cannot use aura:id value because it's selecting all the fax's in the displayed rows when I select one fax button

output is looking like this, imagine phone and fax are buttons

```
0Phone   0Fax
1Phone   1Fax
2Phone   2Fax
```

now I am trying to match the auraId with the rowIndex and change the button variant using and condition, but it is not working.

```
variant="{!(and(v.phoneType == 'phone', v.indexVal == index)) ? 'brand' : 'neutral'}"
```

Is there any way I can make change the button variant on click which is in iteration? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexVar` can't be used as part of another expression - ie you can't compare it to anything.

Because of this, you should use something else as your unique identifier for the row... luckily, you have something - `contactId` (if you don't have it, you can probably get it easily)

So in your button syntax, you would define `variant` and `value` like this:

```
<lightning:button
  variant="{!(and(v.phoneType == 'phone', v.selectedId == con.Id)) ? 'brand' : 'neutral'}"
  value="{!con.Id}"
  .... other attributes
</lightning:button>
```

And in the handler you'd save your value to a new attribute: `selectedId` -

```
var contactId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
component.set("v.selectedId",contactId);
```

Comment: Thanks @Caspar Harmer, but I had tried with the contactId as well, I am able to print the right values on button click, but the variant type is not changing

Comment: ahhh, nevermind, I was making a silly mistake, instead of Id, I was using id in the condition... Thanks for taking time and helping me figure the solution!!